# Why directory __pycache__ is not created after launch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have the very simple script/module "*sc.py*":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

print('Hello stackoverflow!')
```

When I run it on my MacOS (10.13.3) from python interpreter using "*import*" command, like this (run from the same directory where script is placed):

```
$ python3.6
>>> import sc
'Hello stackoverflow!'
>>>
```

the code is works of course and I see that the directory "__pycache__" (where should store the compiled programme "*sc.cpython-36.pyc*") is created in the same directory where "*sc.py*" is placed.

**But** if I run the script simple from the command line like this:

```
./sc.py
'Hello stackoverflow!'
```

or like this:

```
python3.6 sc.py
'Hello stackoverflow!'
```

the code is works of course but the directory "__pycache__" (where should store the compiled programme "*sc.cpython-36.pyc*") is not created.
And I can't find the file "*sc.cpython-36.pyc*" anywhere (using *find* utility for searching from root (/) directory).

Anybody knows why the "__pycache__" is not created?

Comment: The bytecode cache only applies to imported modules.  It's not used for the top-level script that you run.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you a lot! Now I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The `__pycache__` directory is created by Python when it compiles source files to bytecode files (.pyc files). This compilation occurs by default when you import a module, but not when you run a script directly.

When you import sc.py in the Python interpreter, Python compiles it to bytecode and stores it in the `__pycache__` directory.

However, when you run `./sc.py` or `python3 sc.py` directly from the command line, Python doesn't create the `__pycache__` directory or compile sc.py to bytecode because it's being executed as a script, not imported as a module.

Comment: Minor nit that doesn't detract from the overall answer: the script *is* compiled to byte code, but that byte code isn't written to a `.pyc` file. It just stays in memory until the interpreter exits.